# Php Xml loop through addAttribute

Tags: php, xml, attributes, simplexml

How can I loop through addAttribute to write multiple values.

So far it looks like this:

```
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            $this->title->addAttribute('names', "'".$this->Data[$i]->names.';');
        }
```

I get this error:

> SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute already exists

current the xml looks like this(without the loop, with a static value name):

```
<button names=Tim;"/>
```

but I want it to look like this after the loop:

```
<button names=Tim;Tom;Ted"/>
```

how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by first create an array with all your name, and then [implode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) your array in your attribute
This should work

**PHP**

```
$names = [];
foreach($this->Data as $key => $value) {
    $names[] = $value->names;
}
$this->title->addAttribute('names', implode(';', $names));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, you'r trying to add same attribute. Instead of it, you can create an array with names. Then you can join array elements with a glue string with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$names = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  $names[] = $this->Data[$i]->names;
}

$this->title->addAttribute('names', implode(';',$names));
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use [`addAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) to add value to exist attribute. Only add new value to attribute like bottom code

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $this->title['names'] .= $this->Data[$i]->names.';'
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/jdFXY)